# Diffeomorpishm preserves dimension

Tags: inverse-function, nonlinear-analysis, diffeomorphism

Theorem:Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n, V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ are open and $f: U \to V$ is a diffeomprhism with inverse $g : V \to U$. Then

(i) $n=m$, and

(ii) at each $x \in U$ the differentials are invertible linear maps with

$dg_y=(df_x)^{-1}$ or $J_g(y)=(J_f(x))^{-1}$ for $y:=f(x)$.

Proof: We differentiate $id_U=g \circ f$:

$id_{\mathbb{R}^n}=d(id_U)_x=d(g \circ f)_x=dg_{f(x)} \circ df_x$.

Similarly, $id_{\mathbb{R}^m}=df_x \circ dg_{f(x)}$. Thus $dg_{f(x)}$ is invertible with (left and right) inverse $df_x$. This proves (ii) and since $dg_{f(x)}$ is invertible we have $n=m$ which proves (i).

Now my question is why we have assumed that $f$ is a diffeomorphism since we did not use the continuity of the derivative anywhere. I think the same proof should work for a differentiable homeomorphism with a differentiable inverse. The lecture notes also mention that homeomorphism preserve dimension in general, but since the notes lead up to the inverse mapping theorem I am not interested in a general proof here.

I know this might be a simple question, but I am pretty new to homemorphisms and diffeomorphism etc., so I want to make sure I don't misunderstand anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It makes no sense to even talk about $dg$, let alone apply the chain rule if you don't know that $g$ is differentiable.

Comment: All you need to prove $n=m$ is for $f:U \to V$ and $f^{-1}:V \to U$ to be differentiable (at one point $x \in U$ and $f(x) \in V$ respectively). You don't need continuity of the derivative to prove this.

Comment: @Thorgott I agree, but I didn't say that I wanted to drop that assumption.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for confirming my understanding.

Comment: But differentiability of the inverse is what being a diffeomorphism is all about. Continuity of the derivative is indeed not necessary as peek-a-boo points out, but a differentiable homeomorphism will not suffice for this argument to work.

Comment: @Thorgott My lecture notes state: A homeomorphism $f$ is called a diffeomorphism if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuously differentiable. I actually had a differentiable homeomorphism with a differentiable inverse in mind. This should be sufficnet, but as peek-a-book mentioned we actually only need this to be true for one point.

Comment: you should note that the term "diffeomorphism" is used to mean different things in different contexts. I've seen it used in 3 different ways. First is "$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable" (on their domain). Next is "$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $C^{1}$ (or $C^k$ for some $k \geq 1$)" and also as "$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are $C^{\infty}$". Which meaning is intended depends on context, and you should always refer to the definitions provided in that context

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks for pointing that out!